# Query string changes when try to use it.

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I have a query string that looks like this. 
`Page.aspx?s=C94CA8CCAFB12E2B669735186D327D1B3E505538139A66C8455X%2353411389BBB9577E1FD`
Then I have a Button that has a post back that looks like this:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string URL = Request.QueryString["s"];
    Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?s="+URL);
}
```

But when I get to the page 2 the query string that I put in URL changes the % sign into # and the decryption fails because it looks for that % in the string to separate all my pages works with that decryption so I cant change the way that works I need to know why does it change that % into # 
This is how it looks like when it goes to the Page2.aspx

`Page2.aspx?s=C94CA8CCAFB12E2B669735186D327D1B3E505538139A66C8455X#53411389BBB9577E1FD`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%23` is the url-encoded code for the `#` character.  If you look, it's actually replacing the `%23` with `#` and not just the `%`.  You will need to check for that when passing query string information between pages.

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string URL = Request.QueryString["s"];
    Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?s="+UrlEncode(URL));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you check your query string carefully, you will realize that not `%` is replaced by `#`, but `%23`.  That is because the `%` is an escape character and `%23` stands for `#`. You have to escape `%` itself with `%25`:

`Page.aspx?s=C94CA8CCAFB12E2B669735186D327D1B3E505538139A66C8455X%252353411389BBB9577E1FD`

Answer (score 3):

```
string URL = Request.QueryString["s"];
        URL = Server.UrlEncode(URL); // This will allow it to keep the %23 
        Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?s="+URL);
```

As all the answers you got yes thats the reason Encoded Just make sure you tell it its a UrlEncode so it dont change that.

Answer (score 1):

It's being translated as a [URL Encoded character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Note that it's not just the percent sign that is being replaced, but also the `23` that is following it. If you look at the table listed on the Wikipedia page you'll see that `%23` is the `#` character.